# Feed algorithm changed? Lots of duplicates

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

I think the algorithms deciding what I should see in my feed have been changed recently. It used to work very well but for the last week or so I've been getting lots of duplicates (see screenshot attached). Please change it back!

Device: HTC 10

OS: Android 6.01

[image]

Comment: Sorry about this. It's a bug with blog posts being "syndicated" to all sites, and we've been posting more blog posts recently so they show up more and more in the feed. Will get it taken care of.

Comment: Good explanation!